# Подключение к WCF сервису через прокси

Tags: c#, proxy, wcf, .net-core

Пытаюсь выполнить подключение к WCF сервису через прокси. На прокси настроена авторизация по логину-паролю.

Следующий код приводит к ошибке:

```
var proxyHost = "http://127.0.0.1:3128/";
var proxyUserName = "username";
var proxyUserPassword = "userpassword";

var apiConnectAddress = "https://remoteaddress/service.svc";

var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
{
    UseDefaultWebProxy = false,
    ProxyAddress = new Uri(proxyHost)
    Security =
    {
        Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
        Transport = 
        {
            ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic,
            ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic
        }
    }
};

var client = new Client(binding, new EndpointAddress(apiConnectAddress));

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = proxyUserName;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = proxyUserPassword;

client.SomeMethod(...); // здесь возникает исключение

class Client : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T> { ... }
```

Информация об исключении:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException
    HResult=0x80131500
    Message=The remote server returned an unexpected response: (407) Proxy 
    Authentication Required.
    Source=System.Private.ServiceModel
    StackTrace:
        at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
```

Насколько я понимаю, проблема заключается в том, что прокси-серверу не передаются логин и пароль, установленные для клиента. Как выполнить настройку HttpBinding, чтобы успешно подключиться к сервису через прокси?

Comment: Попробуйте задать _None_ вместо _Basic_ для _ClientCredentialType_ (см. [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17968307/2523686)).

Comment: @i-one, да, я видел этот вопрос. При замене `ClientCredentialType` с `Basic` на `None` ничего не меняется - возникает та же ошибка.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/975302/2523686) ещё похожее, но вдобавок советуют выставить `BypassProxyOnLocal` в _false_ (хотя вроде бы оно и так false по-умолчанию). Или там же рядом [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1047883/2523686) с использованием `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` (но тогда `UseDefaultWebProxy` должно быть _true_).

Comment: @i-one, `BypassProxyOnLocal` не помог. Как ни странно, но выставление `DefaultWebProxy` тоже не помогло. Почему-то используется системный прокси (который задается в настройках Windows) и не используется тот, который задается для WebRequest. Возможно, поведение было изменено в .Net Core.

Comment: А на локальном прокси `ProxyCredentialType` точно _Basic_, а не какой-нибудь другой? Или не знаю, может тогда в исходники заглянуть, попробовать логику понять (начать, наверное, [отсюда](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelFactory.cs)).